# Empty method name, what does this actually do?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm currently learning myself objective-c and iOS programming and found myself stuck with non-working code due to this subtle error for an hour.
Consider the following code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
- (NSString *):name { return @"Some name"; }
```

At first glance (and for anyone new) this looks like an overridden getter for the `name` property. But theres a very subtle **:** that shouldn't be there. You get no warning/error from the compiler/parser/runtime here, so my question is what does this actually end up as?

I tried to figure a way of calling this method once I saw the error, but didn't succeed in my few attempts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The method signature `- (NSString *):name` breaks down to the following:

- `-` It is an instance method (versus a class method with a `+`).
- `(NSString *)` It returns a string.
- `:` If you were to speak the name of this method, it would simply be called "colon". `:` tells the compiler that your method accepts one parameter as well.
- `name` There is a parameter called name.

When you don't specify a type, the compiler assumes you meant `id`, so this method actually fleshes out to be `- (NSString *):(id)hello`

A valid call to this method would be: `[self :@"hello"]`.

You can do really weird things because `:` is a valid name for a method, and the compiler assumes `id`. You could, if you really wanted to, have a method called `- :::`. The compiler would assume you meant `- (id):(id):(id):(id)`, a method that returns an object of type `id` and takes three parameters of type `id`. You'd call it like so: `[self :@"hello" :anObject :myObject];`

Comment: +1, simply for `If you were to speak the name of this method, it would simple be called ... colon`.

Comment: Actually, the method name is "empty string".  When speaking method names, you don't generally say the colons, even though they are there... confusing, I know... but it is kinda like ","s in the english language.  A pause or connector, but not spoken.

Comment: @bbum Actually Apple says that the official way to say a method is to say all of the colons. Looking up the line in the docs right now...

Comment: Thanks for a precise answer. A parser warning here would have been nice.

Comment: I'd love to see those docs, Jack, as I'll have a bone -- a colon -- to pick w/the author. :)  The bottom line, though, is that a method named ":" or "::" or ":::" is a sure fire way to earn the ire of any experienced ObjC programmer.

Comment: Yeah, still looking. I know they're in there somewhere. Regardless, I rarely say the colon myself. It's just the "official" way, and Xcode respects it. Try this: open an Xcode project and in your implementation, implement a method called `-:a` and then below it, reimplement the same method. Xcode will give you the error "Duplicate declaration of method '`:`'. But yes. Naming a method `- :::` would be idiotic.

Answer (score 3):

A method declare like the one you posted is rare (and poor style, imo). Objective-C is supposed to be verbose. Methods break down like this:

1. First character: Either `-` or `+`. `-` means it is an instance method, `+` means it is a class method.
2. Value in parentheses: The return type of the method. In your example, the method returns an `(NSString *)`.
3. The rest (before the curly braces) is the method name along with any parameters they take. You could have a name with no parameters, in which case the method name would not have a `:` in it. Such as `- (void) reload;` This would be a method that doesn't return a value and takes no parameters.
4. If your method takes parameters, they will be mixed into the method name and usually will declare the type (unlike your example). Such as `- (NSString *) reverseString:(NSString *) stringToReverse;` In this example your method name would be `reverseString:` it takes one parameter, an `NSString*` that will be called `stringToReverse` in the method definition.
5. Usually, if you see a `:` with no type it will be a case like `- (float) addThreeValues:::` This method returns a float and takes 3 parameters. This would be an appropriate definition because the three values don't matter what order they are provided because we are just adding them.